# Changing Activities

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error when ever I switch between my game activity which uses a surfaceview and my other activities using an inflated menu.

Logcat:

```
07-13 15:15:34.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.hitmanassault/com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1629)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman.onCreate(Hitman.java:42)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     ... 11 more
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView.<init>(HitmanView.java:52)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     ... 21 more
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:464)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:340)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:363)
07-13 15:15:34.594: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15103):     at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView$HitmanThread.<init>(HitmanView.java:158)
```

EDIT:Code for Background Image

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();//Line 156
options.inSampleSize = 2;    // this will cut the sampling by 50%//Line 157
mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background, options );//Line 158
```

EDIT2:Constructor for image

```
public HitmanThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler ) {
this.mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
mHandler = handler;
mContext = context;
mRes = context.getResources();      

paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

paint.setTextSize(16);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;    // this will cut the sampling by 50%
mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background, options );
    }
```

EDIT3:

I tried running my game on a few newer phones using 2.2 and up. It works because without crashing, is there anyway to specify a certain VM budget. Any thing with 16mb or less won't be able to run it sadly. I have 3.4mb of heap with 1mb free any alternative solutions would greatly appreciated.

Comment: the bitmap that you've used is too big , that's why there is an exception of outofmemoryException

Comment: how do I make it smaller, with out changing the dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start at the bottom...

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

coming from

```
at com.android.hitmanassault.HitmanView$HitmanThread.<init>(HitmanView.java:158)
```

I suppose in line 158 of your file HitmanView.java, you're trying to load an obscenely large bitmap?

Comment: my background image, but it shouldn't be doing that. I will edit it to show you the code for it.

Comment: How big is the image?  "OutOfMemoryError" kind of implies your out of memory.

Comment: How big is it in pixels? Also, does this only happen after repeatedly decoding it? Are you leaking it?

Comment: 640px by 400px.I don't believe I am leaking and it only happens when switching between activities, from other activities to my game.

Comment: Do you have a handle on what other allocations you're doing? Maybe you're doing lots of other things, and this allocation is what brings it over the edge. Btw, can you give a little bit more context on where this is happening? I see you have a custom view called HitmanView, and it has its own thread to decode the bitmap? How are those two set up? i.e. what starts the thread, etc?

Comment: It's all ran in one thread, I followed a few examples and tutorials that were based off of the lunar lander and jetboy tutorial. When I get the allocations a  majority of it is coming from onDraw, toString, and <init>.

Comment: 640x400 isn't too much. You must be doing other allocations somewhere. As to your other (new) question, you can't specify the VM budget - after all, your app is supposed to play nice with the rest of the operating system. Older phones have a smaller budget. Did you try DDMS to see how much you have allocated?

Comment: @EboMike I am not sure what to look for, when I go through the allocation tracker and click on the different lines I see that  my onDraw is being called a lot. It keeps calling a canvas.drawText() method I use to display the Lvl, Score, and Health that is constantly being updated.

Comment: OKay, one more thing - do you get the problem only when you're running your app through the debugger, or also when you run it without a debugger attached? Bitmaps leak if you have a debugger enabled. Other than that, there's not that much more I can tell you without seeing more of the code. The bottom line is - you're out of memory. There's SOMETHING that allocates memory. What happens when you remove parts of your code in an attempt to track down the culprit? Obviously, your bitmap is a big allocation, but that by itself shouldn't be enough to exceed the budget.

Comment: When ever I run it in general, I have tried detaching it from debugger. I still get the same results, I've tried only messing with the onDraw method but I will go though and try removing other parts to see. Thanks for all your help.